# Почему не считается count при заданном значении offset?

Tags: mysql, sql

Почему не считается `count` при заданном значении `offset`?

```
select count(*) from `TABLE` where ... offset 0
```

Этот запрос выдает количество записей в таблице. Если поставить `offset = 1`, то база возвращает пустой ответ.

Comment: offset применяется после `group by`, когда вы задаете хотя бы одну групповую функцию (count()) и не задаете group by, то подразумевается группировка всех строк в одну. запрос начинает возвращать одну строку, а offset 1 пытается из этого взять вторую строку

Comment: @Mike `select count('id') from 'TABLE' group by 'id' where ... offset 1`?

Comment: а зачем offset 0? слово offset добавлено только для совместимости синтаксиса с постгре "LIMIT x OFFSET y". Уберите его вообще

Comment: @nup Нет конечно. если вы сгруппируете по id, то получите кучу строк с значением 1 (если конечно с одним id у вас по одной записи). Вопрос только в том, что offset в принципе не имеет смысла при получении count(). Для достижения какого результата вы пытаетесь его применить ?

Comment: Вы явно делаете не то, что хотите. Сформулируйте задачу, а не то, как Вы (неправильно) собрались её решать.

Comment: @Mike, Задача следующая: нужно получить количество записей после считанной. Имитация постраничной навигации с ajax-загрузкой содержимого: сначала получаем 20 записей с 20 по 40, а затем смотрим, сколько еще осталось после 40 (по тем же условиям запроса) и, если это значение равно 0, удаляем кнопку "Показать еще".

Comment: @nup Считанной каким образом ? offset позволяет только задавать количество _пропускаемых_ записей. Если вы хотите посчитать количество записей с пропуском N перед этим то проще просто получить `count(*)-N` это будет то же самое

Comment: И кстати count(*) очень возможно, что отработает быстрее, чем offset, потому что offset сначала читает записи целиком с диска а потом их выбрасывает. А голый count() теоретически может идти вообще по индексу.

Comment: @Mike, насчет `count(*) - N` согласен, почему-то, сам об этом не подумал. Но для считывания самих записей тоже используется `offset`. Это правильно или здесь тоже есть другие варианты?

Comment: Варианты конечно есть, но они настолько муторны в реализации, что чаще всего проще забить на это. Но если очень хочется или смещения бывают большими и все тормозит, то идея заключается в том, что бы сохранять значение ключа сортировки последней выбранной записи и условие `>` на это поле в where. но могут быть всякие подводные камни, вроде не уникальности этого значения и соответственно в необходимости дополнительных условий, что бы найти "ту самую запись"

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за разъяснения. Узнал много нового.